# how to read images in HDF5 format using itk?

Tags: c++, hdf5, itk

I need to read images in HDF5 format in my c++ code. I googled and it seems I can use ITK. Could you please let me know if there is such a possibility?

PS1. HDF5 images are in *.h5 format.

PS2. I'm using ITK to read images like png and jpg formats.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use ITK to read it. A good way to check whether your image file format is supported by the ITK's reader is to try opening your image using [Slicer](https://www.slicer.org/). If the file opens correctly, you are good to go.

If not, ITK might still read it as Slicer essentially only cares about 2D, scalar 3D and some special vector 3D cases.

Comment: Try ImageReadWrite example. You need to adjust your dimensionality and pixel type: https://github.com/InsightSoftwareConsortium/ITK/blob/master/Examples/IO/ImageReadWrite.cxx

Comment: I suppose it is not supported then. I haven't really worked with HDF5, so I can't be of more help.

Comment: What is the image data? If the specification is consistent can you convert into another format ITK can read?